# How to send a form i ionic framework

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Hi everyone I created an app using ionic framework and in the app i created different types of forms. I wish ti know how I can configure these forms in such a way that ones the user has fill them out he/she can send it to a specified email address or phone number if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To make a form send an email you simply set the action attribute to to MAILTO.

```
action="MAILTO:someone@example.com"
```

Phone numbers are a bit trickier, since you need the phone number and then you need to parse that into an actual email that the phone provider/carries uses.
In theory if you have that you can do:

```
 action="MAILTO:PHONENUMBERHERE@CARRIERHERE"
```

You can get carrier like this: https://github.com/dtmtec/cordova-plugin-carrier/

Comment: should I add it in the tag or in javascript

Comment: tag, its an attribute.